# Custom SearchView style not applied

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, searchview

I´m trying to set a custom style on my `SearchView` in the toolbar, but none of the proposed solutions that I´ve found works and the style isn´t applied. I´m using the `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` version of the SearchView.

In the `styles.xml` I´ve created a custom style for the SearchView and applied it to the AppTheme but the appearance of the SearchView doesn´t change. I´ve already tried multiple differen attributes of the style but none changes anything.

**styles.xml:**

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/CustomSearchViewStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomSearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
        <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_custom_search</item>
        <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/custom_search_row</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**menu.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

I just want to modify the clock icon in the recent searches suggestion list, but the custom style isn´t applied and I can´t find any other way to do it.

**Edit 1:**
I´ve just added the same `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView` to a regular layout-file and then the style is applied correctly. However when used as `actionViewClass` in the menu the style is ignored. Do you know how to also apply the style when it is used as `actionViewClass`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57345629/7254873

Comment: To change the icon use `<item name="searchHintIcon">` in your `CustomSearchViewStyle` style

Comment: I´ve tried setting the `searchHintIcon` but it doesn´t change anything aswell.

Comment: @MaximilianSpeicher still looking for an answer?

Comment: @Vince Yes, I still wasn't able to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Answer is applying **only for `androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView`**

Add this to the `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.Toolbar</item>
</style>
```

And remove this item `searchViewStyle` from `AppTheme`

Complete `style`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <!--search view customization-->
    <item name="layout">@layout/abc_search_view</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_clear_material</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="goIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="voiceIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="commitIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line</item>
</style>
```

If you use `NoActionBar` theme (example `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`), then add `searchViewStyle` directly to `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <!--search view customization-->
    <item name="layout">@layout/abc_search_view</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_material</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_clear_material</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="goIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_go_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="voiceIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_voice_search_api_material</item>
    <item name="commitIcon">@drawable/abc_ic_commit_search_api_mtrl_alpha</item>
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

**For support library**

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
ImageView icon = mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);

mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
ImageView icon = mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search); // Here you select your custom icon.
```

**For Android X**

```
MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

mSearchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
ImageView icon = mSearchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search); // Here you select your custom icon.
```

Comment: He is using androidx non support

Comment: I´ve tried it with `findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button)` but nothing changes. Furthermore I try to change the icon in the recent searches list not just the search icon.

Comment: Worked!! For hint icon   `ImageView hintIcon = searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);`